# Why my node running testnet has blocknumber greater than the blocknumber in https://ropsten.etherscan.io/

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan

Why my node running --testnet has blocknumber greater than the blocknumber in https://ropsten.etherscan.io/

my node has above 4000000 blocks but ropsten.ethersca.io showing 3000000 something blocks

> I used command geth --rpcapi personal,db,eth,net,web3 --rpc —testnet

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you passed a long dash "—testnet" instead of a double dash "--testnet", geth will have ignored that parameters and started syncing mainnet.

From the geth console execute `eth.getBlock(0).hash` to check the genesis block:

- Mainnet: `0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3`
- Ropsten: `0x41941023680923e0fe4d74a34bdac8141f2540e3ae90623718e47d66d1ca4a2d`
- Rinkeby: `0x6341fd3daf94b748c72ced5a5b26028f2474f5f00d824504e4fa37a75767e177`
- Kovan: `0xa3c565fc15c7478862d50ccd6561e3c06b24cc509bf388941c25ea985ce32cb9`

Comment: Holy crow my hash is 0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3 its from main net , i was under impression i was downloading ropsten. thanks you saved my ass.